# Restarting x-axis for consecutive domains on Plotly

Tags: python, graph, plotly, networkx

I have the following function that draws a graph on plotly figure. I want the figure to restart x-axis on each domain starting position (stored in ‘domain’ attribute of the networkx graph) as in the matplotlib examples in the attached figure.

My code is

```
def draw_plotly_domains(G,title):
    positions=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
    domains=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'domain')
    final_positions = {}
    for pos, dom in zip(positions.items(), domains.items()):
        label, (x, y) = pos
        _, d = dom
        idx_dom = int(d_to_idx[d])
        final_positions[label] = [x + domain_starts[idx_dom-1], y]

    edge_x = []
    edge_y = []
    for edge in G.edges():
        x0, y0 = final_positions[edge[0]][0],final_positions[edge[0]][1]
        x1, y1 = final_positions[edge[1]][0],final_positions[edge[1]][1]
        edge_x.append(x0)
        edge_x.append(x1)
        edge_x.append(None)
        edge_y.append(y0)
        edge_y.append(y1)
        edge_y.append(None)
    edge_trace = go.Scatter(
        x=edge_x, y=edge_y,
        line=dict(width=0.5, color='#888'),
        hoverinfo='none',
        mode='lines')

    node_x = [] # position
    node_y = [] # copy number
    node_id = [] # node id
    node_chr = []
    for node in G.nodes():
        x, y = G.nodes[node]['pos']
        node_x.append(x)
        node_y.append(y)
        node_id.append(node)
        node_chr.append(int(df[df['Source']==node].Domain.values[0])) # item() returns numbers as str
    

    unique_values = len(set(df.Domain.to_list()))
    unique_values = len(set(node_chr))
    color_bar_values = [val for val in np.linspace(0, 1, unique_values+1) for _ in range(2)]
    discrete_colors = [val for val in px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet for _ in range(2)]
    colorscale = [[value, color] for value, color in zip(color_bar_values, discrete_colors[1:])]
    colorscale.pop(0)
    colorscale.pop(-1)

    ### Compile hover text for each node
    node_text = []
    for n,node in enumerate(G.nodes()):
        next_node='None' if n==len(G.nodes())-1 else ','.join(str(i) for i in df[df['Source']==node]['Sink'].to_list() if i!='loose')
        prev_node='None' if n==0 else ','.join(str(i) for i in df[df['Sink']==node]['Source'].to_list())
        node_text.append(f'Prev: {prev_node}<br><b>-Node:{node}-</b><br>Next: {next_node}<br>Domain: {node_chr[n]}<br>CN: 

    node_trace = go.Scatter(
        x=node_x, y=node_y,
        mode='markers',
        hoverinfo='text',
        text=node_text,
        marker=dict(
            showscale=True,
            colorscale=colorscale,
            reversescale=True,
            color=node_chr,
            size=10,
            symbol=0,
            colorbar=dict(
                thickness=15,
                title='Domain Number',
                xanchor='left',
                titleside='right'
            ),
            line_width=2))

    fig = go.Figure(data=[edge_trace, node_trace],
                layout=go.Layout(
                    title=title,
                    titlefont_size=16,
                    showlegend=False,
                    hovermode='closest',
                    margin=dict(b=20,l=15,r=5,t=40),
                    annotations=[ dict(
                        text=f"Number of nodes: {len(node_y)}",
                        showarrow=False,
                        xref="paper", yref="paper",
                        x=0.1, y=1 ) ],
                    xaxis=dict(showgrid=True, zeroline=True, showticklabels=True,showline=True,title_text = "Start Point"),
                    yaxis=dict(showgrid=True, zeroline=True, showticklabels=True,showline=True,title_text = "Amplitude")
                    )
                    )
    fig.show()
```

As you may notice, I created the position of each node with the dictionary final_positions so that each node can be placed accordingly on the x-axis. So, domains contribute to the x-axis position but I don’t want to see this cumulative sum on the x-axis but the restart x-axis with each domain starting point. The contribution of each domain by their length is given in the following code block

```
domain_lengths = {'1': 250_000_000,
                '2':   245_000_000,
                '3':   200_000_000,
                '4':   195_000_000,
                '5':   185_000_000,
                '6':   175_000_000,
                '7':   160_000_000,
                '8':   146_000_000,
                '9':   142_000_000,
                '10':  136_000_000,
                '11':  136_000_000,
                '12':  135_000_000,
                '13':  116_000_000,
                '14':  108_000_000,
                '15':  103_000_000,
                '16':  91_000_000,
                '17':  82_000_000,
                '18':  80_000_000,
                '19':  60_000_000,
                '20':  64_000_000,
                '21':  48_000_000}

domain_starts = []
start = 0
domain_starts.append(start)
for cl in chr_lengths.values():
    start += cl
    domain_starts.append(start)
```

I’d appreciate any help. At the moment, x-axis is just one piece and node positions are not correct. For simple test case, you can use the following networkx graph (not the same graph in the picture I share, but should be helpful enough)

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1534, pos=(22803603, 7), domain=1)
G.add_node(945, pos=(32494954, 5), domain=5)
G.add_node(946, pos=(32530403, 3), domain=6)
G.add_edge(1534, 945)
G.add_edge(945, 946)
```

P.S.: The grids on the figure should be placed whenever x-axis becomes zero again but I haven't fix it yet.

[image]

[image]